# What part of Hangman repeats the letter

Tags: python

I have trouble here.

In the Hangman Game **(Python)** .

What is the part of this code that makes this:?

**For example:**

> (The Secret Word is "door")
>
> **_ _ _ r**
>
> Guess the letter: o
>
> **_ o o r**    <---puts 2 times the letter "o"

Here is the code:

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''

  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''']
words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print('Missed letters:', end=' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks: # show the secret word with spaces in between each letter
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    # Returns the letter the player entered. This function makes sure the player entered a single letter, and not something else.
    while True:
        print('Guess a letter.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Please enter a single letter.')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('You have already guessed that letter. Choose again.')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please enter a LETTER.')
        else:
            return guess

def playAgain():
    # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


print('H A N G M A N')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    # Let the player type in a letter.
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        # Check if the player has won
        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print('Yes! The secret word is "' + secretWord + '"! You have won!')
            gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

        # Check if player has guessed too many times and lost
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
            displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('You have run out of guesses!\nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses, the word was "' + secretWord + '"')
            gameIsDone = True

    # Ask the player if they want to play again (but only if the game is done).
    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part right here:

```
blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

for i in range(len(secretWord)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

for letter in blanks: # show the secret word with spaces in between each letter
    print(letter, end=' ')
```

Comment: Another thing, what means this colons??    blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

Comment: What means the colons inside the lists? blanks[:1]

Comment: @a7xrturo: String slicing. That `blanks[:1]` is the first character of `blanks`. Read a Python tutorial.

Comment: Of course, all this can be replaced with `' '.join(ltr if ltr in correctLetters else '_' for ltr in secretWord)`.